# AForge VideoCapabilities error

Tags: c#, aforge

As I'm looking in the souce code of the AForge library, I was wondering what was wrong with this line:

```
ulong key = ((capabilities.FrameSize.Height << 0x20) | (capabilities.FrameSize.Width << 0x10)) | ((ulong)capabilities.FrameRate);
```

Operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'ulong'
this is the error given, the thing is I don't know how to fix this line.

kind regards